# Efficient way to check a particular string in object (one of it's property) in array (other than loop condition) in iOS obj c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsobject

I implemented using for loop `+ isEqualString:` method to check the string in array which is stored as an object contains property. I am checking property of the obj in array.

any other best way to lookup string in array?

```
FMResultSet *resultsWithEmployee = [fmDatabase executeQuery:sqlSelectQuery];
while([resultsWithEmployee next]) {
    aCustomer = [Customer new];
    aCustomer.gFirstname = [resultsWithEmployee stringForColumn:@"FIRSTNAME"];
    aCustomer.gLastname = [resultsWithEmployee stringForColumn:@"LASTNAME"];
    aCustomer.gEmailID = [resultsWithEmployee stringForColumn:@"EMAIL"];
    aCustomer.gPassword = [resultsWithEmployee stringForColumn:@"PASSWORD"];
    aCustomer.gDOB = [resultsWithEmployee stringForColumn:@"DOB"];

     NSLog(@"Customer object %@", aCustomer);
    [customerArray addObject:aCustomer];
}
[fmDatabase close];
return customerArray;
```

NOTE : customer is a NSObject class and it has 5 properties such as firstname ,lastname ,email ,password ,DOB.

Comment: What type of objects do you store in array, can you share the code you're using now?

Comment: Yes.I thanked for code formatting @fogmeister.

Comment: Maybe create an NSMutableDictionary of the properties and just check if "objectForKey" ? If you are only checking if the property exists. but if you want to compare it with another NSString, you could do "if objectForKey" "if isEqualString" , that way you check if the object exists, and after that you only do the comparison, instead of doing string comparisons for every single object.